# PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb is not working in SharePoint 2013, CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, client-object-model, publishing-site, office-365-developer

```
    var pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(context, context.Web);
        context.Load(pWeb);
        if (pWeb != null)
        {
           <This condition is true for Team and Publishing Site Both>
        }
```

This code is not working, it's going in if condition, if we provide Team site context as well..

```
        using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(webUrl))
        {


            var pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(clientContext, clientContext.Web);

            clientContext.Load(pWeb);

            if (pWeb != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Web : " + webUrl + " is a publishing web");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Web : " + webUrl + "is not a publishing web");
            }
        }
```

I have already included - `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing` .. REFERENCE AND NAMESPACE in my project

I am using SharePoint 2013. Kindly suggest what is the issue here? why it's going in if condition for team site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to determine whether site is a Publishing site using CSOM:

```
public static bool IsPublishingWeb(Web web)
{
     var ctx = web.Context;
     var propName = "__PublishingFeatureActivated";
     //Ensure web properties are loaded
     if (!web.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated("AllProperties"))
     {
         ctx.Load(web, w => w.AllProperties);
         ctx.ExecuteQuery();
     }
     //Verify whether publishing feature is activated 
     if (web.AllProperties.FieldValues.ContainsKey(propName))
     {
         bool propVal;
         Boolean.TryParse((string)web.AllProperties[propName], out propVal);
         return propVal;
     }
     return false;
}
```

> Compatible with SharePoint 2010/2013

Usage

```
   using (var ctx = GetSPOContext(webUri,userName,password))
   {
        var web = ctx.Web;
        if(IsPublishingWeb(web))
        {
           //...
        }
   }
```

Comment: +1, Definitely a cleaner approach than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `ClientContext.ExecuteQuery`. After `clientContext.Load(pWeb);` use `clientContext.ExecuteQuery();`

**UPDATE**

It appears that `PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb` creates a PublishingWeb object whether the site is a publishing site or not. As you may be aware the PublishingWeb has a Pages library, the workaround can be to check whether a library with this name exists or not in the Web. Example:

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://aissp2013/sites/T1"))
{
    PublishingWeb pWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(clientContext, clientContext.Web);
    ListCollection listCollection = pWeb.Web.Lists;
    clientContext.Load(listCollection, lists => lists.Include(list => list.Title).Where(list => list.Title == "Pages"));
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    if (listCollection.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Web is publishing");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Web is not publishing");
    }
}
```

However, this is not a foolproof method as user can create Document Library named Pages in a site.

**UPDATE 2**

A better way of finding whether a web is publishing or not is to check whether Publishing Feature is activated on it or not. Here is the code:

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://aissp2013/sites/T1"))
{
    bool isPublishingWeb = false;
    Site site = clientContext.Site;
    FeatureCollection features = site.Features;
    clientContext.Load(features);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    Guid publishingFeatureID = new Guid("f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa");
    foreach (Feature feature in features)
    {
        if (feature.DefinitionId == publishingFeatureID)
        {
            isPublishingWeb = true;                       
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isPublishingWeb)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Web is publishing!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Web is not publishing!");
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Hello Nadeem, Thanks for the quick response. I have added suggested piece of code as well, but no luck :(

    using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(webUrl))
    {
    var pWeb =   PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(clientContext, clientContext.Web);
    clientContext.Load(pWeb);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    if (pWeb != null)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Publishing Web");
    }
    else
    {
     Console.WriteLine("Non-Publishing Web");
    } 
    }

Comment: Is the site a team site. Has the Publishing feature been activated in this site?

Comment: No publishing feature is not ON. It's a team site only

Comment: You need to turn on SharePoint Publishing feature in order to use `PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb`

Comment: The problem is .. it's showing all web as a publishing web even-though it's a team site. My requirement is.. it should show publishing web only if it's a publishing site or publishing feature is activated in any site

Comment: @VirendraKumar, I did not properly read the question initially, See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Nadeem. I am also using similar kind of workaround. As we know this solution will fail if we have library with "Pages" name. That's why I asked question in forum.

`Web web = clientContext.Web;
ListCollection listCollection = web.Lists;
clientContext.Load(listCollection);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

bool pagesListAvailability = false;
foreach (List oList in listCollection)
{
    if (oList.Title.Equals("Pages"))
    {
        pagesListAvailability = true;
    }
}

if(pagesListAvailability)
{//PublishingWeb}else{//Non-PublishingWeb}`

Comment: @VirendraKumar, check my updated answer.